# Custom function in H2 Database for test class in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

My application is based on Java and Spring framework and Oracle Database, where in my application I am using below query to fetch data.

Query:

```
select sub.subscriber_id
RTRIM 
( xmlagg (xmlelement (c, subsrc.source_cd || ',') order by subsrc.source_cd).extract ('//text()') 
, ',' ) AS subscribed_sourceCodes 
from DR_DBA.submodule sub, DR_DBA.submoudle_source subsrc, DR_DBA.source src 
where subsrc.subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id 
        and subsrc.source_cd = src.source_cd 
        and sub.active_in = 'Y' 
        and src.subscribed_in = 'Y' 
group by  sub.subscriber_id;
```

Above query is working as excepted in SQL developer as well as in application.

while writing integration test class, We have decided to H2 database to create in memory database for testing purpose. But its failing for above mentioned query with below error

Error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select sub.subscriber_id
RTRIM 
( xmlagg (xmlelement (c, subsrc.source_cd || ',') order by subsrc.source_cd).extract ('//text()') 
, ',' ) AS subscribed_sourceCodes 
from DR_DBA.submodule sub, DR_DBA.submoudle_source subsrc, DR_DBA.source src 
where subsrc.subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id 
        and subsrc.source_cd = src.source_cd 
        and sub.active_in = 'Y' 
        and src.subscribed_in = 'Y' 
group by  sub.subscriber_id;"; expected "[, ., ::, AT, FORMAT, *, /, %, +, -, ||, NOT, IS, ILIKE, REGEXP, AND, OR, ,, )"; SQL statement:
select sub.subscriber_id
RTRIM 
( xmlagg (xmlelement (c, subsrc.source_cd || ',') order by subsrc.source_cd).extract ('//text()') 
, ',' ) AS subscribed_sourceCodes 
from DR_DBA.submodule sub, DR_DBA.submoudle_source subsrc, DR_DBA.source src 
where subsrc.subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id 
        and subsrc.source_cd = src.source_cd 
        and sub.active_in = 'Y' 
        and src.subscribed_in = 'Y' 
group by  sub.subscriber_id;  [42001-220]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:910)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:5793)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfMore(Parser.java:1312)
```

Given that I have created custom functions for xmlagg , xmlelement  and RTRIM.
Post debugging , got to know that error is occurring cuz of **"order by subsrc.source_cd).extract ('//text()') "**

any solution ? like how to tackle this situation. Given that, We cant change the query

Created Custom functions as these below functions are not supported by H2

schema.sql

```
drop ALIAS if exists XMLAGG;
CREATE ALIAS XMLAGG as '
import java.lang.*;
@CODE
java.lang.String toDate(String s) throws Exception {
  return "";
}
'
```

schema1.sql

```
drop ALIAS if exists XMLELEMENT;
CREATE ALIAS XMLELEMENT as '
import java.lang.*;
@CODE
java.lang.String toDate(String s, String dateFormat) throws Exception {
  return "";
}
'
```

schema2.sql

```
drop ALIAS if exists RTRIM;
CREATE ALIAS RTRIM as '
import java.lang.*;
@CODE
java.lang.String toDate(String s, String dateFormat) throws Exception {
  return s;
}
'
```

URL : jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=ORACLE;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:./schema.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:./schema1.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:./schema2.sql'

Answer (score 0):

Using H2 to test queries that use vender-specific features is not a good idea. Sure, you can try to define your own funcitons for missing functionality, but that is only one out of enormous problems that you are going to face. You can try to launch H2 in Oracle mode using `MODE=Oracle` in your jdbc url in tests for H2, but that will mitigate only some problems and it is not designed to cover all details of the underlying Oracle database, only the most basic ones.

I highly suggest you to use [testcontainers project for Oracle](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/oraclexe/).

> Given that, We cant change the query

This is exactly why testcontainers lib exists, becuase some SQL queries can be executed only by very specific vendor. This lib will just launch a docker process of the RDBMS you have, such as Oracle in your case, and therefore the query does not need to change, since in your tests you are using a lightweight Oracle database, not H2.